# GWT dev mode not refreshing when client code changes

Tags: gwt

Dev mode works fine, but if I change client code and refresh the browser it doesn't see the code changes.  I'm using maven, with the following gwt plugin config.

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
        <executions>
           <execution>
              <goals>
                 <goal>browser</goal>
                 <goal>run</goal>
                 <goal>debug</goal>
                 <goal>compile</goal>
                 <goal>test</goal>
                 <goal>i18n</goal>
                 <goal>generateAsync</goal>
                 <goal>resources</goal>
              </goals>
           </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
           <runTarget>simmapp/simmapp/template/Login.vm</runTarget>
           <hostedWebapp>${war}</hostedWebapp>
           <servicePattern>redangus/client/**/*Service.java</servicePattern>
           <generateDirectory>${target}/generated-sources/gwt</generateDirectory>
           <modules>
              <module>redangus.Inventory</module>
           </modules>
           <deploy>${target}/extra</deploy>
           <!--war>${war}</war-->
           <!-- If you don't have this, an empty JspFactory sneaks in and
           breaks the tests. -->
           <gwtSdkFirstInClasspath>true</gwtSdkFirstInClasspath>
           <runClasspathExcludes>
              <runClasspathExclude>javaee-web-api-6.0.jar</runClasspathExclude>
           </runClasspathExcludes>
           <sourceLevel>1.7</sourceLevel>
           <persistentunitcache>true</persistentunitcache>
           <persistentunitcachedir>${basedir}/persistent</persistentunitcachedir>
        </configuration>
     </plugin>
```

The command line produced and run by netbeans with the classpath hacked out:

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_21.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java -Xmx1024m -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8000,suspend=y -classpath whatever -Dgwt.persistentunitcache=true -Dgwt.persistentunitcachedir=/Users/tom/git/reds_gwt/persistent com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode -deploy /Users/tom/git/reds_gwt/target/extra -gen /Users/tom/git/reds_gwt/target/.generated -war /Users/tom/git/reds_gwt/target/simmapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT -logLevel WARN -port 8888 -codeServerPort 9997 -startupUrl simmapp/simmapp/template/Login.vm -logdir /var/log/tomcat redangus.Inventory

Comment: How are you starting dev mode. Are you using super dev mode, or the browser plugin dev mode?

Comment: Chrome browser plugin, mvn gwt:debug

Comment: You may have to _clear_ _your_ _cache_ _first_ as browser is going to retrieve the same js as before.